# Cannot build freshly-made Maui App due to NU1301 "The local source ... doesn't exist" error referencing a different VS project

Tags: c#, maui, visual-studio-2022, maui-blazor

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (Community Version) to try and create a mobile application using the Maui Blazor template.  As soon as I create the project, before I do anything else, the error list is filled with 164 errors stating that:

> "The local source '...source\repos(Completely different project in my repos directory)...\bonuspkg doesn't exist."

The error apparently comes from my .csproj file in line 1, which also doesn't add up.

I am attempting this project targeting .net 7.0, I previously tried 6.0 but got the exact same issue.

I've seen no mention of anyone else having this issue so I'm assuming something is wrong with my visual studio or I made a mistake in setting up the project, but the errors provide no useful information for identifying it.

I've tried rebuilding the project, switching .net versions, cleaning the project, checking properties , checking nuget packages, and reinstalling the templates in VS installer, in all cases the errors persisted.  I can't even identify where in the project it is trying to reference the bonuspkg.

Comment: Just created one with no error. Update your VS, and check VS installer if SDK and all necessary components for Maui and Blazor have been installed. Or post all your screenshots about your creation process, so we can help.

Comment: I would delete all versions of VS, reboot, install again. Delete broken projects. Make a fresh one.

Comment: please share your .csproj and .sln files

Comment: You can try to reinstall the whole visual studio and make sure you have install all the workload.

Comment: I am running into this problem too, and updating/reinstalling did nothing.